# Cursor with two tables

Tags: oracle11g, cursor

I am trying to use a cursor to pick all values with a select statement. Now once I do that based on the store number from this select statement I want to select all those features who overlap/interact with each other([SDO_RELATE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14255/sdo_operat.htm#i78531))

Below is the block of SQL.

```
Declare 
  BG_TOTAL number;
 l_area number  ;
 STORE_NUMBER number;
 cursor c1 is 
    select *
     from table 1
      where CLIENT_ID= 1 and status is null and rownum < 2 ;

  Type SITE_TAB_TYPE is table of  c1%ROWTYPE;

  SITE_LIST SITE_TAB_TYPE;

Begin
  open c1;
  FETCH c1 BULK COLLECT INTO SITE_LIST;

  close c1;

    For i in 1..SITE_LIST.count loop

    Select
   a.store_number,a.client_id,a.geometry
    from table 2 a, SITE_LIST b
    where SITE_LIST(i).STORE_NUMBER
    AND SDO_Relate(a.geometry,b.geometry,'mask=anyinteract') = 'TRUE';
```

Comment: Why can't you do a simply select on table1 join table2?

Comment: @DanBracuk these tables are too big to be joined. And I want them to go to a new table since I will be using that to clean the geometry for the further selected stores.

Comment: Why are they "too big to be joined?"  Are there no indexes?

Comment: @OldProgrammer dont want them to be joined. Want them in a new table and then work on the geometry on it separately.

Comment: Wouldn't it be a good idea then, to join them and store the results of that query in the new table?

Comment: So do a "insert into <table> select ..."